Maven - how find the version of a parent of a dependency
is it possible to find the right version of a parent
where the LIB is used
for example
I use spring-boot-starter-web v1.0.2 which has the dependency of spring webmvc v4.0.3
but how find that
spring webmvc v6.0.0 => spring-boot-starter-web v...
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/6.0.0
here I see only the usage
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/usages
but not the matching version
thx in advance
Greetings
Klaus

You can see a list of compile dependencies here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/6.0.0. It means that spring-webmvc requires spring-aop starting from version 6.0.0.
At the same time spring-boot-starter-web includes spring-webmvc dependency and you don't need to warry about compatibility issues in this particular case.
Also you can run mvn dependency:tree in terminal on the same FS level where your pom.xml exists and you will get the transparency what libraries are pulled.

I saw the list
but that links only to the common site of spring-boot-starter-web
and not of the version which uses spring-webmvc v6.xxx
I have now manually looked for it
and find that
spring-boot-starter-web v3.0.0 uses spring-webmvc v6.xxx
a way by tool whould be nicer :)

Update:
I have found now a better page
https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/6.0.2/dependents
which shows for ""spring-boot-starter-web" the right version of "3.0.0"
the only drawback is, that I have to check different version of "spring-webmvc"
